# Azure Copy Files from AZDatalake to AZBlob sorage Dynamic

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, etl, azure-data-factory

I want to copy files from azure data lake storage to azure blob storage. when i use static file name it's copying successfully but it is not getting success while using dynamic file name.

I have followed same process as per below blog but getting String type conversion error.

ErrorMessage:
Error code : 2200

Failure type : User configuration issue

Details:
ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'fileName' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,'

Reference Blog : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/extract-file-names-and-copy-from-source-path-in-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Want to add a suggestion. When we convert a V2 storage to Data Lake V2 storage  there are some basic validation are being done. e.g. Versioning should be disabled. Some of the Data Lake folders might not support to get migrated. Same thing is applicable to Data Lake to blob container as well. So if possible check the Data. Issue will be related to data only.

Comment: The method you used is working fine for me. The error message indicates that there is a cast exception while reading the payload value. Please provide sample file data, storage directory structure and the dynamic content you added so that the problem can be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "***WILD CARD***" filtering in the copy activity.

Set the wildcard folder path : `rootFolder/subFolder/*/*/DestinationFolder`

Choose the wildcard file name = * or *.json or *.txt or *.csv.., etc according to the requirement.

Check the following link for detailed understanding :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store?tabs=data-factory#folder-and-file-filter-examples